# Ember.js + Ember Data + PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ember.js

I'm having trouble understanding how to connect Ember.js with PostgreSQL using Ember Data adapter.

My main problem is finding a complete example where I can study how I would do this.

I know I have to create a jsonapi to provide the data. My goal is using Node.js to provide the data. 
I've found this project [here](https://github.com/holidayextras/jsonapi-server) and I see that it has a relational db [store](https://github.com/holidayextras/jsonapi-store-relationaldb).

Anyone knows where I can find a complete example of a project using Ember with a PostgreSQL jsonapi server implemented in Node.js?

Preferably a simple project where I can understand the basics of getting a connection running and show the data in Ember.

Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [boilerplate node app](https://github.com/JakeDluhy/node-boilerplate) and a [boilerplate ember app](https://github.com/JakeDluhy/ember-boilerplate) that are designed to work together as a frontend/backend app. They aren't especially simple, but if you explore them you might be able to gain some good insight into how these two frameworks can connect.

For example, in the [users controller](https://github.com/JakeDluhy/node-boilerplate/blob/master/app/controllers/users.js), the show method maps to /users/:id, and then responds with a custom JSON payload conforming to JSON API spec. Although it hasn't been implemented yet, in Ember simply having `this.store.findRecord('user', 1)` will automatically send a request to /users/1.

You can explore the config files to look at the postgres connection (I implemented using [bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) and [knex](http://knexjs.org/)).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two questions here. You first need to choose how nodejs communicates with your ember-data. [This](https://github.com/holidayextras/jsonapi-server) is a possible approach. It also provides a [connector](https://github.com/holidayextras/jsonapi-store-relationaldb) to your database. 
Secondly, you need to define how nodejs communicates with the db. [Here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/modules#db-pg) is a list of possible packages that might fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, if you read my question you'll see I have included the sites you mention. My problem is that I'm not understanding yet how to use them,  so I asked if someone has a complete example or some other info where I can study how to do it :)